# Python: List of Lists, Change from Strings to Ints

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
x =[['+1', '+2', '+3', '+4', '+5', '+6']] 

y = [['+1', '-3', '-6', '-5'], ['+2', '-4']]
```

Is there anyway to change my list of lists from Strings **to** Integers?

I tried

```
def changy(foo):
    new = []
    for i in xrange(len(foo)):
        r = map(int, foo[i])
        new.append(r)
    return new
changy(x)
```

when I run

```
print changy(y)
```

my output is exactly what I want

```
[[1, -3, -6, -5], [2, -4]]
```

whenever I run x I get

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '+'

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Beside the fact that you return `news` instead of `new`, your code works fine under Python 2.7.

Comment: @alecxe Which is my point, his code works.

Comment: sorry about the wrong return i just fixed it

Comment: When you tried this with `x`, you probably had an unnested list `['+1', '+2', '+3', '+4', '+5', '+6']`.

Comment: comment below really helped me with my nested loop to handle the nested list. thanks to everyone who took time to look at this question! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '+'` means that you're first iterating the main list, then the nested list and then the characters in the string itself; that's one level "too far"/deep.

You can use a two-dimensional list comprehension. `int()` correctly interprets "+" and "-" as meaning positive and negative numbers:

```
>>> y = [['+1', '-3', '-6', '-5'], ['+2', '-4']]
>>> [[int(d) for d in z] for z in y]
[[1, -3, -6, -5], [2, -4]]
>>>
```

You can use `map` in this way as well:

```
>>> y = [['+1', '-3', '-6', '-5'], ['+2', '-4']]
>>> [map(int,z) for z in y]
[[1, -3, -6, -5], [2, -4]]
>>>
```

Comment: hey thank you! did you just double loop through my nested list?

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation, that makes  perfect sense.

Comment: @Qbert I think so, yeah. First, it iterates all the lists in the main list `y` and then all the strings within each nested list.

Answer (score 1):

```
def changy(n):
    return [[int(d) for d in z] for z in n]

print changy(x)    
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]

print changy(y)
[[1, -3, -6, -5], [2, -4]]
```

n = (a nested list)

the above comment helped me realized I was iterating to far into my list.

This function helped me change my String nested lists to Integer nested lists.